# setuptools: include converted data files into the wheel, keeping originals in the source distribution

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

In my case, parsing the original data is slower than deserialising pickles. I'm trying to transform data during `setuptools` build:

```py
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py

ROOT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
DATA_DIR = ROOT / 'data'
OUT_DIR = ROOT / 'src' / 'package'

class BuildPy(build_py):
    def run(self):
        # Turn files from DATA_DIR into pickles in the OUT_DIR.
        build_py.run(self)

setup(
    ...,
    cmdclass={'build_py': BuildPy},
    package_data={"package": ["*.pickle"]}
)
```

Unfortunately, `setup.py` is executed in a temporary directory, and thus it doesn't find any `data/*`:

```text
* Building wheel...
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build-via-sdist-dkhq2z2i/package-0.0.1/data/file.txt'
```

Equally bad, `sdist` ends up having neither `data/*` sources nor pickles. Adding `data/*` to `package_data` results in both original and converted files to be present in the resulting wheel.

How to get original `data/*` files in the source distribution and transformed in the binary wheel?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html -- Also if it were me I would place the serialized (pickled) data in the *sdist* as well. My logic is that if it is multi-platform then it can be placed in the *sdist* already, no need to wait until wheels are built.

Comment: `data` in `MANIFEST.in`, `*.pickle` in `package_data`, and `data/*` in `exclude_package_data` does the trick. Please convert your comment into an answer, so that it can be accepted.